# Node-red MSSQL-PLUS issue with mustache format for server name and user/pwd

Tags: node-red, mustache

I'm using mssql-plus 0.6.4 version.

I could not connect to sql using env variable for connection informations. This is helpful for me to connect to different db located in the different location. I tried to create a sub flow for sql that would help me reuse the same flow across different locations with different servers.
It throws me an errr message

> code: "ESOCKET" message: "Failed to connect to :1433 - Could not
> connect (sequence)

you help would be really appreciable.
I've attached the flow with subflow

```
[{"id":"ebc85c42.463a8","type":"subflow","name":"SQLPlus064","info":"","category":"","in":[{"x":100,"y":80,"wires":[{"id":"bf1289cd.07fcb8"}]}],"out":[{"x":300,"y":80,"wires":[{"id":"bf1289cd.07fcb8","port":0}]}],"env":[{"name":"ServerName","type":"str","value":"10.1.2.111"},{"name":"UserName","type":"str","value":"appliUser"},{"name":"Password","type":"str","value":"1234556"},{"name":"DBName","type":"str","value":"DB_DEV"}],"color":"#DDAA99"},{"id":"bf1289cd.07fcb8","type":"MSSQL","z":"ebc85c42.463a8","mssqlCN":"c29068d1.97ef38","name":"","outField":"payload","returnType":0,"throwErrors":1,"query":"Select TOP 10 * FROM TestBenchResult","modeOpt":"","modeOptType":"query","queryOpt":"","queryOptType":"editor","paramsOpt":"","paramsOptType":"none","params":[],"x":200,"y":80,"wires":[[]]},{"id":"c29068d1.97ef38","type":"MSSQL-CN","z":"ebc85c42.463a8","tdsVersion":"7_4","name":"DB-Con","server":"\"ServerName\"","port":"","encyption":true,"trustServerCertificate":true,"database":"ShopfloorDB_DEV","useUTC":false,"connectTimeout":"50000","requestTimeout":"50000","cancelTimeout":"50000","pool":"5","parseJSON":false,"enableArithAbort":true},{"id":"c81636eb.e7d248","type":"tab","label":"MSSQLPlus-CheckSub","disabled":false,"info":""},{"id":"7c1a36cd.c54a88","type":"inject","z":"c81636eb.e7d248","name":"","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":120,"y":100,"wires":[["30366732.3efba8"]]},{"id":"de6a1325.7c759","type":"debug","z":"c81636eb.e7d248","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":440,"y":100,"wires":[]},{"id":"30366732.3efba8","type":"subflow:ebc85c42.463a8","z":"c81636eb.e7d248","name":"","env":[{"name":"ServerName","value":"10.1.2.111","type":"env"},{"name":"Password","value":"123456789","type":"str"}],"x":300,"y":80,"wires":[["de6a1325.7c759"]]}]
```

In the documention, feature list included as  below

[image: feature list]
please let me know if you need any further details.

we really need this as we have more locations for which we cannot create different flows for same set of actions

Thanks
Ramesh R

Comment: This is already being worked through on the forum, cross posting isn't likely to get anybody new to look at it

Comment: @hardillb, thanks for mentioning. Sorry, I'm not aware of it. Just in case someone could give me a solution